# how to remove SphereVisual3D object for simulation in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: How it looks now]

I am trying to simulate a ball getting thrown away with physics.
The moving part already works with my calculations but i cant seem to remove the previous ball, the ball is an SphereVisual3D object.

This is how the golball is made.

```
class GolfBall
{
    public void CreateBall(HelixViewport3D Viewport, double x, double y, double z)
    {
        Viewport.Children.Add(Balll(x, y, z));
    }
    public void DeleteBall(HelixViewport3D Viewport, double x, double y, double z)
    {
        Viewport.Children.Remove(Balll(x,y,z));
    }
    
    private SphereVisual3D Balll(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        var ball = new SphereVisual3D
        {
            Center = new Point3D(1.5, 12, -1.5),
            Radius = 5,
            Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 197, 147))),
            Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(x, y, z)
        };
        return ball;
    }
}
```

(MainWindow.xaml.cs)In this part of the code the ball gets created, but the method DeleteBall doesnt seem to work to delete the previous ball. And i dont get an error for the method.

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    time += timer.Interval;
    deltaT = time - firstTick;
    firstTick = time;
    
    this.ball.DeleteBall(Viewport, BulletX, BulletY, 50);
    Vy += YAcceleration;
    BulletX += Vx;
    BulletY -= Vy;

    
    ball = new GolfBall();
  
    ball.CreateBall(Viewport, BulletX, BulletY, 50);
    
}
```

I also tried to remove the ball with this code
`Viewport.Children.Remove(ball);`
in my MainWindow.xaml.cs in the method timer_tick but than i get this error:

> 'Argument 1: cannot convert from '_1819apep3dewulfflorian.GolfBall' to
> 'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Visual3D'   1819apep3dewulfflorian'

Sorry for my bad english.
If I forgot anything to make it clear u can always tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Why don't you create a ball and then move it?

Comment: @Roberto Hello, i wouldnt know how to do that. doesnt that make it way more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a simple example:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:helix="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800" Height="450"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="viewPort" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Mover" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using HelixToolkit.Wpf;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace WpfApp10
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        SphereVisual3D ball;
        double x = 5;
        double y = 0;
        double z = 0;
        double acceleration = 0.5;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ball = new SphereVisual3D
            {
                Center = new Point3D(1.5, 1, 1),
                Radius = 0.5,
                Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 197, 147))),
                Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(x, y, z),
                Visible = true
            };
            viewPort.Children.Add(ball);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (y < -5)
            {
                y = 2;
            }
            if (x < -5)
            {
                x = 2;
            }
            if (z > 5)
            {
                z = -2;
            }

            y -= acceleration;
            x -= 0.5;
            z += 0.5;
            ball.Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(x, y, z);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know so much about 3d effects in wpf.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: It definitly helped me out getting more understanding on how to do it different thanks a lot. I was able to make it work :)  (but still in a different way)